# Drush module could not be downloaded

Tags: drupal, drush

I'm trying to do a simple `drush dl drupal` but I got this error:

```
➜  drush dl drupal    
copy(/tmp/drush_tmp_1499421442_595f5b0280292/tar: Failed to set default locale): failed to open stream: No such file or directory filesystem.inc:268 [warning]
Project drupal (8.3.5) could not be downloaded to /xxx/test/drupal-8.3.5. [error]
```

I tryed to `chmod -R 777 /tmp` (/private/tmp) but nothing change. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by adding these lines in my `~/.bashrc`

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_COLLATE=C
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: And in Windows? Do you know where I can find that bashrc file?